# Uso da palavra "cenário" quando o contexto envolve dois cenários distintos

Tags: uso-de-palavras, significado-em-contexto

Existe um modelo, um esqueleto, de redação circulando pela internet, para as pessoas que estão estudando para vestibulares, que é mais ou menos assim:

> *Na obra "Utopia" do escritor Thomas More, é retratada uma sociedade perfeita, na qual o corpo social padroniza-se pela ausência  de conflitos e problemas. No entanto, o que se observa na realidade contemporânea é o oposto do que o autor **prega**, uma vez que a intolerância religiosa apresenta barreiras, as quais dificultam a concretização dos planos de More. Esse **cenário antagônico** é fruto tanto do preconceito, quanto da falta de informação. Diante disso torna-se fundamental a discussão desses aspectos, a fim do pleno funcionamento da sociedade.*

Eu estranhei o trecho '**cenário antagônico**', porque na minha cabeça o livro apresentaria um cenário e a realidade apresentaria outro cenário, mas no contexto desse trecho de texto a palavra '**cenário**' está sendo usada para apresentar livro+realidade. Esse é um uso correto da palavra 'cenário'?

Aproveitando a pergunta, outra dúvida que tive sobre esse mesmo trecho é o uso da palavra '**pregar**', que para mim significaria algo como "afirmar enfaticamente". Entretanto, o livro citado é uma obra de ficção, nesse caso o uso da palavra '**prega**' seria correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que ambos os usos estão corretos.

- "*Esse cenário antagônico*", refere-se ao cenário da "realidade contemporânea" que, com sua intolerância, é oposto ("antagônico") à sociedade perfeita que More descreve.
- *Pregar* é: fazer propaganda, apregoar, exaltar, difundir, evangelizar, etc. O fato de se tratar de um trabalho de ficção não o impede de pregar: vide fábulas e parábolas, com suas morais.

Não li o livro, mas pela [descrição](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(book)) na Wikipedia, a interpretação dominante é se tratar de uma crítica à sociedade da época e apresentação (sincera ou sarcástica) de uma alternativa socialista, a da ilha de Utopia. Portanto o uso da palavra "pregar" sugere que o autor do trecho do modelo de redação toma a descrição de Utopia como uma proposta sincera.

Comment: A propósito, não vem muito ao caso mas, na minha opinião, esse trecho de texto não tem qualidade o bastante para ser exemplo de redação. Dois exemplos concretos: melhor que "barreiras, as quais" seria "barreiras que"; e falta um verbo em "a fim do pleno funcionamento", como "de se atingir o", além de que "pleno" não parece muito adequado ao contexto.

Comment: Obrigado @stafusa! De fato, marquei bobeira, eu primeiro pensei no cenário referente ao livro, mas não fazia sentido, depois pensei que o cenário podia fazer referência a livro+realidade e aí me pareceu errado, mas, de fato, não tinha pensado no cenário referente à realidade, que é antagônica referente ao livro... aí fez todo o sentido, grato! E, verdade, pregar nesse sentido também faz sentido.

Comment: Sobre seus comentários, também senti a mesma coisa em relação à qualidade do texto e também estranhei esses "as quais" que poderiam ser "que" e ficaria bem melhor. Não tinha nem percebido o "a fim do pleno funcionamento", mas de fato falta um verbo ali!

Comment: Pois é, @PedroGaspar, e a tua confusão sobre a qual cenário ele se referia também é sinal de que o texto poderia ser melhor.